# Can't find CSS files on server, when they are there

Tags: html, css

This all worked fine when running a local server.

I have header.html, which has this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/header_style.css">
```

In the public_html directory, the same directory as the header.html file, i have the `header_style.css` file.

It manages to find all images, linked like so:

```
<img src="/images/logo.png"/>
```

So I don't know why it's having trouble finding my CSS file.

Any ideas?

Comment: People asks about paths errors but don't show their folder structure... did your banner.html is on the public_html folder too ?

Comment: Check your browser's console, you'll most likely see an error of an external resource not being loaded, check the actual path being requested there

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone.  Combining `web` and `server` doesn't mean you're talking about a web server.  You have enough rep here to know this already...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `/` at the beginning of the `href` in your `link` to `header_style.css`.  It's not required and some servers may interpret this as 'return to root' which may or may not be the directory you expect it to be.

Answer (score 2):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="header_style.css">
```

if it is in the same directory u dont need to use the /