# CSS present in the local environment, but not the server environment

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with CSS showing up on my server environment. I've tried setting the `href` to `/css/style.css` and including the `type="text/css"` header, however nothing is working. The CSS shows up in the local environment just fine, and when I go to my website and visit the developer network tab, it shows an old version of the CSS. I am saving the document.

Header code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css"/>
```

CSS code:

```css
body {
    margin: 2vh;
    margin-left: 6vh;
    margin-right: 6vh;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Any solutions are appreciated.

Comment: what is the website link?

Comment: Please have a look at this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19142887/cant-find-css-files-on-server-when-they-are-there

Comment: The website link is https://teknet.app/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative path in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028561/relative-path-in-html)

Comment: No. When I visit my local site, even with the relative path in my code, it works, however on Cloudflare and my IPv4 address, it does not work. Only solution is with `/style.css?v1` however I'm looking for a more automatic solution.